# iOS 11: badge value stuck after receiving remote notification

Tags: notifications, push, ios11, badge, apn

I have an iPhone Application since many years.
Since iOS 11 release I have problem with App Icon Badge managment.
I use the following line to set its value :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = nbMessages;
```

All works fine until the device receive a remote notification that sets the badge value.
After the app receive a remote notification the value of the badge is frozen. It stays at the value of the last delivered notification.
(The app doesn't use local notifications)

There is no problem with iOS 10 and it seems there is no change between iOS 10 and iOS 11 API of the notification center.

There is no problem with iOS 10.